# Codigniter query returning wrong count

Tags: jquery, database, codeigniter, model

I am using code igniter and I am building a query to return how many people attended an event. So I can take the number and try to work out a percentage.

The issue I am having is I am trying to build the query according to Codeigniter 3 Docs, But I am returning the wrong result for some reason and simply cannot figure out why.

First of all here is the table in my database I am querying:

[image: my database]

Here is the function I am calling from my controller:

```
public function get_event_attendance_percentage($id) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('attendance');
        $this->db->where('event_id', $id );
        $this->db->where('attended', 1 );
        $attendancecount = $this->db->get();
        return count($attendancecount);

    }
```

I am selecting all from my attendance table, I am then stating I want all attendance from event with id 17 then I am also stating where attended is = 1

I want to return the number 3 but I am returning number 1.

Can anyone help me see where I am going wrong please?

---

I got this working with the grateful help of @Vickel. Here is the query that returned the correct result:

```
public function get_event_attendance_percentage($id) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('attendance');
        $this->db->where('event_id', $id );
        $this->db->where('attended', 1 );
        $attendancecount = $this->db->get();
        return $attendancecount->num_rows();
    }
```

Comment: Also please refer my answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54658052/codigniter-query-returning-wrong-count/54659050#54659050

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`count()` is a [php built-in function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php), and in the way you use it, it "counts" the query string, therefore returns 1, no matter what

the correct CI way is to use `return $attendancecount->num_rows()`: see [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-helper-methods)

Comment: Hey Vickel, Many thanks for your kind suggestion, I did try this already but I got an error stating this: CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to string? I need to echo out the result in the view as a string.

Comment: You were correct Vickel! I simply had it organised slightly wrong. I will post the working snippet in my original question. Thank you for kindly taking the time to help me. I really appreciate it!

Comment: check with  `echo $attendancecount->num_rows();die();` if the rows are correct, the other error can result from how you continue processing the return

Answer (score 1):

IF you want just count number of rows, you can use $**this->db->count_all_results()** as below.

```
public function get_event_attendance_percentage($id)
{
        $this->db->where('event_id', $id );
        $this->db->where('attended', 1 );
        $this->db->from('attendance');
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```

Check CodeIgniter Manual => https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=count_all#limiting-or-counting-results

NOTE :-

**num_rows()** :- With *num_rows()* you first perform the query, and then you can check how many rows you got. **Useful when you need table data**.

**count_all_results()** :- With *count_all_results()* you get the number of rows your query would produce, but doesn't give you the actual resultset. **Useful when you need just rows count** for i.e. pagination, display no. of records etc.