# I am getting Unsupported operand types error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I try to add pagination links, I am getting **Unsupported operand types error**

Here is my code

### Model

```
public function getCategory($limit,$offset){

    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("tbl_category");
    $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);

    $row = $this->db->get()->result_array();

    return $row;
}

public function num_rows(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_category');
    $row = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    return $row;
}
```

### controller

```
public function category($script="list",$id=""){
    $data['script'] = $script;

    if($script == 'list'){

        $config = [
            'base_url' => base_url('http://localhost/training/admin/'),
            'per_page' => 2,
            'total_rows' => $this->admin_model->num_rows(),
        ];
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $rows = $this->admin_model->getCategory($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
        $data['rows'] = $rows;
    }
```

In my View file I do this to get links

```
<?php $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

### The error I get is like below

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Unsupported operand types

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\training\system\libraries\Pagination.php

Line Number: 412

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\training\application\views\category.php
Line: 101
Function: create_links

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\training\application\controllers\Admin.php
Line: 150
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\training\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: Display function is working fine the only problem is that i am not getting links of pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Controller function, when you get your results, you have to pass it to your View file as below.

```
$data['rows'] = $rows;

// load the view
$this->load->view('category_view', $data);
```

Then in your view file, you can get pagination links.

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

**EDIT =>** Here in config array `'total_rows' => $this->admin_model->num_rows(),` you are assigning an array instead of a count number.

Your Model function is

```
public function num_rows(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_category');
    $row = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    return $row; //This $row is an Array, NOT count no. of rows
}
```

In above function you are returning `return $row;` which is an array. And *this is the reason you are getting an error like Unsupported operand types error*

So 2 solutions to this. **Try only ANYONE of the solution.**

**Either
1)** You have to return the count of the resultset to the total_rows variable:

```
$config = [
            'base_url' => base_url('http://localhost/training/admin/'),
            'per_page' => 2,
            'total_rows' => count($this->admin_model->num_rows()), //Pass the count of returned array.
        ];
```

**OR
2)** You can change in function.

```
public function num_rows(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_category');
    $row = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    return $row->num_rows(); //Return count result instead of array.
}
```

***NOTE :-*** IF you want just count number of rows, you can use **$this->db->count_all_results()** as below.

```
public function num_rows(){
    $this->db->from('tbl_category');
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```

**num_rows()** :- With *num_rows()* you first perform the query, and then you can check how many rows you got. **Useful when you need table data**.

**count_all_results()** :- With *count_all_results()* you get the number of rows your query would produce, but doesn't give you the actual resultset. **Useful when you need just rows count** for i.e. pagination, display no. of records etc.

Refer my another answer here.
[Codigniter Query Returning wrong count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54658052/codigniter-query-returning-wrong-count/54659050#54659050)

Answer (score -1):

[image: Here is my code]

```
 $mess_fees = $this->db->query("SELECT sum(t2.amount) as mess_fees FROM `mess_fee_head` as t1 JOIN mess_fee_detail as t2 ON t1.id=t2.mess_fee_head_id WHERE t1.batch=$student_batch_id AND t1.academic_year_id=$newstudent_acedemic_year_id AND t2.status='Y'")->result();
 $num=4;
 $mess_fee_amount=($mess_fees)/$num;
```